# An equivalent to an NSTimer for a background Audio app?

Tags: ios, background, mpmovieplayercontroller, nstimer, screen-lock

I have a video streaming app that is properly set up to play video via AirPlay while the device is locked or in the background.  It works great.  However, the one thing that doesn't work when the app goes into the background is the NSTimer I use to send an update back to a server once every 10 seconds.  I've read through countless posts about NSTimers not working when an app is in the background.  There are lots of proposed hacks and kludges, but I didn't find the proper way to do this, or if there even is a proper way.

However, since mine is an audio app where some background processing is permitted, I would expect there might be some way to periodically send a post to a remote server.

Is there a preferred way to do this?

Thanks,
Craig